# Is there a way to fake the ADB device, or modify adb.exe/build tools?

Tags: android, adb

I am doing some investigation of a closed-source app using ADB. I would like to log the commands this app is making, the ADB binaries it uses are in the same directory. Would I be able to sniff the commands by faking an ADB device or maybe modding the source code of the build tools to include a log?

Best regards.

I tried using some apps on a physical android device to log the incoming packets, though I got nowhere. I expect to be able to know what this closed source app is doing on my device.

PS: I am sorry if this sounds dumb, I know ADB is open source, part of the Android Open Source Project, but I made this post to make sure I am not missing some small detail. I am not an expert in the ADB protocol so excuse my clumsiness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Answer:

*Copied from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72003057/12206612) to [How to fetch ADB shell traffic?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72002754/12206612)*

It is as simple as listening on the ADB server's port through [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) (TCP port 5037) since all the commands pass through the adb server/daemon before going to USB.

It is also possible to sniff the USB traffic using [USBPcap](https://desowin.org/usbpcap/), as it also is unencrypted.